# How to efficiently find correlation and discard points outside 3-sigma range in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, statistics, correlation

I have a data file `m.txt` that looks something like this (with a lot more points):

```
286.842995
3.444398
3.707202
338.227797
3.597597
283.740414
3.514729
3.512116
3.744235
3.365461
3.384880
```

Some of the values (like `338.227797`) are ***very different*** from the values I generally expect (smaller numbers).

- So, I am thinking that 
  I will remove all the points that lie outside the `3-sigma range`. How can I do that in MATLAB?
- Also, the bigger problem is that this file has a separate file `t.txt` associated with it which stores the corresponding time values for these numbers. So, I'll have to remove the corresponding time values from the `t.txt` file also.

I am still learning MATLAB, and I know there would be some good way of doing this (better than storing indices of the elements that were removed from `m.txt` and then removing those elements from the `t.txt` file)

Comment: The outliers look like they might be formatted with the decimal point in the wrong place.  If that's the case, you could take the solutions below and replace the "erase" step with `m(idx) = m(idx)/100;`

Comment: that's a really good observation! Usually data cleanup is one the most important and difficult step in data mining/analysis.

Comment: @mtrw no they are not decimal point misplacements. it looks like that though!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

@Amro is close, but the FIND is unnecessary (look up logical subscripting) and you need to include the mean for a true +/-3 sigma range. I would go with the following:

```
%# load files 
m = load('m.txt'); 
t = load('t.txt'); 

%# find values within range
z = 3;
meanM = mean(m);
sigmaM = std(m);
I = abs(m - meanM) <= z * sigmaM;

%# keep values within range
m = m(I);
t = t(I);
```

Comment: It may be more natural to reverse the inequality in I, and keep the values you want, i.e. `I = abs(m - meanM) < z * sigmaM; M = M(I); t = t(I);`

Comment: @Richie. True. I'll change it.

Answer (score 4):

```
%# load files
m = load('m.txt');
t = load('t.txt');

%# find outliers indices
z = 3;
idx = find( abs(m-mean(m)) > z*std(m) );

%# remove them from both data and time values
m(idx) = [];
t(idx) = [];
```

Comment: no need for complicated methods, sometimes simple solutions are best!

Comment: Also, you might find this answer to a similar question useful:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1636683/find-only-relevant-points-in-matlab/1640298#1640298